# I would like to create a Macro within an Excel Workbook that will compare tables in another workbook to corresponding tables in DBX

Tags: excel, vba

I am very inexperienced with VBA but I am trying to create a macro in and Excel Work Book that will compare static data in another workbook to its corresponding table in SQL DBx

I can successfully pull the information from my Source Work Book. However some of the data is not being copied accross from the Source Workbook if the data type changes from numberic to string.I would also like to copy headers. I have copied this sub below

I was also hoping to create an Output of the entries that are different in each of the tables? Is this possible

```
Sub Comparison()

Sub Comp()

'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded Aking

Dim aCtiveBook As String

x = 1
    Do While x <= 9


            aCtiveBook = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0)

            Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
            Dim rt As ADODB.Recordset
            Dim cm As ADODB.Command
            Set rt = New ADODB.Recordset
            Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
            With cn
                .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
                .ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & aCtiveBook & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
            .Open



                                Sheetq = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("B1").Offset(x, 0)
                                Sheetn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("C1").Offset(x, 0)


                                rt.Open "Select * from" & "[" & Sheetq & "$" & "]", cn

                                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheetn).Select
                                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheetn).Range("A1:BA20000").Delete

                        Sheets(Sheetn).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rt
                        rt.Close


                        rt.Open "Select * from [" & Sheetq & "$" & "A1:Z1" & "]", cn

                        Sheets(Sheetn).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rt
                        rt.Close

                    End With
                x = x + 1

    Loop


End Sub
```